# Class,Methods in C# Namespaces

Tags: c#, class, methods, namespaces

How can I see all class and methods in any namespace? For example : I install some nuget api and using this namespace of api. I want to know which class and methods are include this namespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display classes of a namespace in visual studio (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855176/display-classes-of-a-namespace-in-visual-studio-c)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Object browser in Visual Studio is what you want? In the menu of Visual Studio under View?